# How to exit factory mode?

Tags: samsung

I have a SAMSUNG Galaxy Young GT-S6312. It entered into Factory Mode one day on it's own. I wanted to exit factory mode so I rooted my device using Kingoroot. I did the following after rooting :-

1. Installed ES File Explorer.
2. Enabled root explorer in it and set the configuration to Mount R/W.
3. Went to the efs of my device.
4. I saw only 4 items - bluetooth, wifi (both folders), .nv_state and nv.log.
   I can not find the FactoryApp folder that should have contained the "keystr" and "factorymode" which I was supposed to change to ON in the text editor.

Now I do not have these files so how am I going to exit factory mode and get back into user mode?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all contents in your **efs** directory.Then reboot your phone.

Comment: That does not solve my problem after rebooting bluetooth and wifi folder are back and there is nothing else in the efs folder.

Comment: @Pranay have you tried executing a hard reset on your phone?

Comment: I have not done it after deleting contents of my efs directory.